# Relacing a word in an db2 sql file causes DSNC105I : End of file reached while reading the command error

Tags: sql, unix, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I have a dynamic sql file in which name of TBCREATOR changes as given in a parameter.

I use a simple python script to change the `TBCREATOR=<variable here>` and write the result to an output sql file.
calling this file using `db2 -td@ -vf <generated sql file>`gives
 `DSNC105I : End of file reached while reading the command`

Here is the file i need the TBCREATOR variable replaced:

```
CONNECT to 204.90.115.200:5040/DALLASC user *** using ****@
select REMARKS from sysibm.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBCREATOR='table' AND NAME='LCODE'
@
```

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# #------replace table value with schema name
# print(list_of_lines)
fin = open("decrypt.sql", "rt")
#output file to write the result to
fout = open("decryptout.sql", "wt")
for line in fin:
    fout.write(line.replace('table', 'ZXP214'))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

After decryptout.sql is generated I call it using `db2 -td@ -vf decryptout.sql`
and get the error given above.

Whats irritating is I have another sql file that contains exactly same data as decryptout.sql which runs smoothly with the `db2 -td@ -vf ...`  command. I tried to use the unix command `cmp` to compare the generated file and the one which I wrote, with the variable `ZXP214` already replaced but there are no differences. What is causing this error?.

here is the file (that executes without error) I compare generated output with:

```
CONNECT to 204.90.115.200:5040/DALLASC user *** using ****@
select REMARKS from sysibm.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBCREATOR='ZXP214' AND NAME='LCODE'
@
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that specifically on the https://ibmzxplore.influitive.com/ challenge, if you are using the java db2 command and working in the Zowe USS system (Unix System Services of zOS), there is a conflict of character sets. I believe the system will generally create files in EBCDIC format, whereas if you do

```sh
echo "CONNECT ..." > syscat.clp
```

the resulting file will be tagged as ISO8859-1 and will not be processed properly by db2. Instead, go to the USS interface and choose "create file", give it a folder and a name, and it will create the file untagged. You can use

```sh
ls -T
```

to see the tags. Then edit the file to give it the commands you need, and db2 will interoperate with it properly. Because you are creating the file with python, you may be running into similar issues. When you open the new file, use something like

```py
open(input_file_name, mode=”w”, encoding=”cp1047”)
```

This makes sure the file is open as an EBCDIC file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Db2-LUW CLP (command line processor) that is written in c/c++ and runs on windows/linux/unix, then your syntax for `CONNECT` is not valid.

Unfortunately your question is ambigiously tagged so we cannot tell which Db2-server platform you actually use.

For Db2-LUW with the c/c++ written classic `db2` command, the syntax for a type-1 `CONNECT` statement does not allow a connection-string (or partial connection string) as shown in your question.  For Db2-LUW `db2` clp, the target database must be externally defined (i.e not inside the script) , **either** via the legacy actions of  both `catalog tcpip node...` combined with `catalog database...`, **or** must be defined in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` configuration file as plain XML.

If you want to use connection-strings then you can use the `clpplus` tool which is available for some Db2-LUW client packages, and is present on currently supported Db2-LUW servers. This lets you use Oracle style scripting with Db2. Refer to the online documentation for details.

If you **not** using the c/c++ classic `db2` command, and you are instead using the emulated clp written in java only available with Z/OS-USS, then you must open a ticket with IBM support for that component, as that is not a matter for stackoverflow.